# Sum rows after a specific column for uncertain number of columns

Tags: r

Let's say i want to sum values of rows in several data frames. I want to start with column 2 and sum every value, that comes after that column. The different data frames may have different numbers of columns though. I guess it can work with

`rowSums(df[2:X])`.

I just dont know, what to replace the X with. Or is there a totally different way of doing it?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ncol` to get column number :

```
rowSums(df[2:ncol(df)])
```

You can also use `length`.

```
rowSums(df[2:length(df)])
```

Comment: Yep, thats exactly, what i was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In case you only want to exclude the first column you can write:

```
rowSums(df[-1])
```

or

```
rowSums(df[,-1])
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I actually might use this in the future as well!